# How to add column in document library in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I am trying to make a customized site Content and I have made it successfully on Document library.While uploading it gets uploaded well but the by default behavior of document library shows me  three but default column which is there in the image

1)Name
2)Modified
3)Modified By

I want to add 4th Column with user input named as a description. 
Image is as follows:[how to add Column in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQIsX.png)

Comment: Have you tried creating new column and check if its visible when you upload new document?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood from your issue is, your column is getting created but not visible on view. When you create column column has property as SPField.ShowInDisplayForm , SPField.ShowInViewForms like properties. Its a Boolean value.